# PDF Read text and add image references

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I am writing application which gets questions from pdf format 
and converts it into moodle format. However, i have a problem.
How can I read pdf file so that text and images will be extracted and 
there will be references for this images in text?

For example, if I read the question from pdf with picture i will get

text:

QUESTION 2

View the Exhibit to examine the description for the SALES table.
Which views can have all DML operations performed on it? (Choose all that apply.)

[image.jpg]

A. CREATE VIEW v3
AS SELECT * FROM SALES
WHERE cust_id = 2034
WITH CHECK OPTION;

B. CREATE VIEW v1
AS SELECT * FROM SALES
WHERE time_id <= SYSDATE - 2*365
WITH CHECK OPTION;

C. CREATE VIEW v2
AS SELECT prod_id, cust_id, time_id FROM SALES
WHERE time_id <= SYSDATE - 2*365
WITH CHECK OPTION;

D. CREATE VIEW v4
AS SELECT prod_id, cust_id, SUM(quantity_sold) FROM SALES
WHERE time_id <= SYSDATE - 2*365
GROUP BY prod_id, cust_id
WITH CHECK OPTION;
Answer: AB
Section: (none)
Explanation/Reference:

and image.jpg with picture of table will be saved in the specified folder.

Thanks for any help in advance. =)

Comment: Is the PDF tagged? How are the images stored in the PDF? DCTDecode? Flatedecode?

Comment: The PDF files I need work with are not tagged. Images in these files use both DCTDecode and FlateDecode (some of them DCTDecode some of them FlateDecode ).

Comment: Not tagged means: more difficult to extract the questions correctly. DCTDecode means you'll be able to extract the images as JPEGs. Flatedecode: you can choose which output format to use, but be aware that images with transparency will result in two images: the opaque image and its mask.

Comment: Is the 'natural reading order' of the text preserved in your PDFs? Or is the content added in random order? (In other words: does the parser need to rearrange the text and image snippets based on their location?)

Comment: How can I find out is the natural reading order is preserved in my PDFs?

Comment: Try this code sample: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275 It lists all the text snippets in your PDF. In the example, "Hello World" is listed as "Hello World" in one case, and as "ld", "Wor", "llo" and "he" in the other. In the former case, the natural order is preserved, in the latter it isn't. In your case: your images could be present on a completely different place in the content stream.

Comment: When I apply method extractText from this tutorial on needed pdf I get text of only first page of this pdf file. The result looks like

Comment: <<L><e><a><d><2><p><a><s><s><.><1><Z><0><-><1><4><7><.><v><1><2><.><4><7>>
<<Nu><m><b><e><r>>
<<: 1><Z><0><-><1><4><7>>
<<P><a><s><s><i><n><g>< S><c><o><r><e>>
<<: 8><0><0>>...

Comment: You only get the first page because you've defined it that way in this method: reader.getPageN(1); Change the 1 into another page number, and you get the content of the other pages. As you can see, your PDF cuts the words into small snippets. Now you need a tool like iText to find which parts fit together. You have a lot of programming work to do to distinguish different questions, answers and images... Note that TextRenderInfo also reveals coordinate info; just extend the example.